# Recaptcha not showing on contribution form

Tags: contributions, recaptcha

I have registered my recaptcha with Google as instructed in the documentation.  I have then created a profile and set the advanced setting to include recaptcha.  Added that profile to a contribution form and nothing is showing.  So as a test, I added a field in the profile and the field is showing on the form but no recaptcha.  Thought maybe something is wrong with my install so I went to the Civi Sandbox and tried it, but still it is not showing.  So I must be doing something wrong, but cannot figure out what that is.
Thx
John

Comment: John - I don't see why this would be CMS related - but we have it working on multiple Drupal installs, mostly on 4.6.x - which sandbox did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found the problem and it was my idiocy.  I was trying to get it to show as a logged in user, and it was not.  When I went as an anonymous user, it shows up just fine.  It totally makes sense, just was not immediately obvious to me.

John

Comment: Glad you found the answer John, please go ahead and mark your own answer as correct.